# ImportError when importing numpy under Spyder from within a Python 3.7 conda environment

Tags: python, numpy, conda, spyder, environment

I have created a conda environment named `python3` on my Ubuntu virtual machine using:

```sh
conda create -n python3 python=3.7
```

I have installed several packages under this environment, including numpy. When typing `conda list`, numpy shows up:

[image]

When running Python from the terminal, I can import numpy just fine, but this is no longer the case when working under the Spyder IDE: I get the following error:

> ImportError: No module named numpy

Just for the record, I have reinstalled Spyder3 from my conda environment (`sudo apt-get install spyder3`) and I am launching Spyder from within this environment.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apt-get installation of Spyder does not know about your conda environment.  You should use conda to install Spyder to the environment.  Activate the environment, then launch Spyder.

```
conda install -n python3 spyder
conda activate python3
spyder
```

Comment: Ha! It did the trick! Thank you for your quick reply, James! Do you know if it is mandatory to specify `-n python3` after `conda install`? In any case, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are IN the environment (i.e. you already ran `conda activate python3` this session), then it is not necessary.