# Cannot import packes from within conda virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, conda

I am using Python 3.8 on a Ubuntu 20.04 computer. So far, I had no problem importing packages from either Spyder of Jupyter.

I have created a conda virtual environment called `theory` using Python 3.6, as confirmed by running `python --version` from within this conda environment.

`conda list` reveals that numpy is installed:

**numpy                     1.19.4                   pypi_0    pypi**

Opening a Python interactive session from the terminal and importing numpy in there works like a charm.
However, when trying to import numpy from within Spyder, I am getting a "Module Not Found" error:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'**

Here is what I tried to fix this issue:

- I tried uninstalling and reinstalling numpy using `pip install numpy` (and `pip3 install numpy`).
- I tried updating conda following the answer provided in [this GitHub post](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8716): `conda update --prefix /home/sheldon/anaconda3 anaconda` .
- I tried specifying the path to the numpy package in the PYTHONPATH manager directly in Spyder, pointing to /home/sheldon/anaconda3/envs/

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** I checked that Numpy 1.9.4. actually supports Python 3.6

**EDIT:** Just recreated a new Python 3.6 environment from scratch and I can import numpy just fine...

Comment: Try this. Within Spyder, go to Tools-->Preferences-->PythonInterpreter, and choose the file called python.exe under `envs/theory`. Then close and re-open Spyder. The path to your **envs** folder depends upon your os, I think it is under your Anaconda folder. Note -- this worked for all my previous conda envs, but didn't work for my most recently created conda env, for some reason. For that, I had to actually install spyder-kernels package within the env itself, and run spyder from within that conda env (using conda command-line). Can't say I understand much, just thinking out loud.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried all possible interpreters (python, python3, python3.6, python3.6m) in `anaconda3/envs/theory/bin` but all of these made the kernel crash. I had to revert back to the default interpreter (*i.e.* the same as Spyder).

Comment: The interesting thing is that in spite of having a Python 3.6 installed, Spyder indicates to be running under Python 3.8.5. I wonder if this could be the cause of my problem.

Comment: Yes, showing the wrong version of Python could be the clue. My other suggestion might work. (Installing spyder-kernels within the env -- after activating the env. Then, running spyder from the conda env itself). Sorry to be throwing blind suggestions, without full knowledge. Just in case you're in the mood for it.

Comment: [This old question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631847/importerror-when-importing-numpy-under-spyder-from-within-a-python-3-7-conda-env?rq=1) and its answer seem to be still relevant for your current problem.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this :

uninstall numpy with pip uninstall
and re install it with

```
conda install numpy
```

Not pip install..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried installing numpy using conda but it did not work. Seemed like a good idea, though!

Comment: @Sheldon Oh sorry to hear. But still I am thinking your problem is related to the pip / conda conflict..    "To create an environment with a specific package:"    

`conda create -n myenv numpy`    ..  try to create venv with conda too.. ?  please see  here [link](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands)

Comment: Yes I confirm that the virtual environment was created using condas.